# filter by uri param in kibana

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a rest endpoint like below:

```
GET /files/{id}/properties
```

I want to filter this endpoint by uri in kibana discover tab but I don't know how to write a regex like '/files/*/properties' in kibana. I store the endpoint uri in uri field. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to use regex directly in kibana but you could use regex in Kibana Filter as you could edit the filter directly. You could add a random filter in your kibana, and then click to edit your filter as this: **[Works if you are using a tokenizer that does not include `/`]**

```
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "uri": {
        "value": "/files/.*/properties"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For how to add and edit a filter: [See this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/field-filter.html)

**Update:**

Just tried, it seemed that if you are using default tokenizer, your url will be tokenized as `["files", "${id}", "properties"]`. In such case, I think you cannot get a full search using the regex. Regex only works on a single word. I think in such case you should go with phrase match:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "uri": {
        "query": "files properties",
        "type": "phrase",
        "slop": "2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See documentation here about [phrase match with slop](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/slop.html).